# How to transfer JSON data to SQL and put the appropriate data into a specific table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, json, database, insert

I am trying to transfer a JSON database to SQL: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/6bzx-emuu/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD

But the problem I have is that how can I insert the data in the appropriate table when the only thing that separates each data is just a comma.

Thanks

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?  Also post some sample JSON along with the desired results.  The link is not helpful / dead.

Comment: What language are you using? just SQL? or is there a script or app of some type?

Comment: @SinthiaV I am using Python on Jypiter to transfer the data to a MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

This will break the string into an array at the commas and trim whiteespace.

```
my_string = "blah, lots  ,  of ,  spaces, here "
[x.strip() for x in my_string.split(',')]
```

Then you loop through the array elements in Python and insert each in turn using a parameterized SQL statement. The idea is to do all the string-manipulation work in Python until you have a record ready to insert. then use Python to build and exeecute your SQL statement.